# C# FileStream - Reader/Writer on a file, on a per line basis - Flush or FileLock?

Tags: c#, file, filestream, streamwriter

I have a StreamWriter with an AutoFlush = true property. However, I still see the file only partially written when I randomly open it. I'm writing a file that needs to be fully written (JSON) or not during any given time.

```
        var sw = new StreamWriter("C:\file.txt", true /* append */, Encoding.ASCII) { AutoFlush = true };
        sw.WriteLine("....");

        // long running (think like a logging application) -- 1000s of seconds

        sw.Close();
```

In between the sw.WriteLine() call and sw.Close() I want to open the file, and always have it be in the "correct data format", i.e. my line should be complete.

Current Idea:

Increase the internal buffer of FileStream (and/or StreamWriter) to let's say 128KB. Then every 128KB-1, call .Flush() on the FileStream object. This leads me to my next question, when I do call Flush(), should I right before calling it get the Stream.Position and do a File.Lock(Position, 128KB-1)? Or does Flush take care of that?

Basically I don't want the reader to be able to read the contents in between Flush(), because it'll maybe partially broken.

Comment: what reader are you using? StreamReader?

Comment: The reader application is unknown, i.e. many readers can be watching the file.

Answer (score 0):

Basically I don't want the reader to be able to read the contents in between Flush(), because it'll maybe partially broken.

I take it you have one open stream.
There is a writer and a reader.
The reader should not read until the flush is completed.

You'll need to use the manual lock mechanism that releases after your flush call.
You can implement in-line or if this is constantly used you can create a thread-safe stream.